# SQLite - iOS - How to count the number of bitwise operators

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

I am trying to dynamically construct a SQLite `SELECT` statement that will count the number of successful `&` operations across several columns.

My database structure has 8 columns (named `C1` through `C8`) Each contains a `0` or `1` in them. I have many rows of course.

I am trying to construct a SELECT statement that counts the number of successful `&` operations such as:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (C1 & 1) + SELECT (C2 & 0) + SELECT (C3 & 1) + ... + SELECT (C8 & 0))
```

But unfortunately, this syntax does not work. The `1's` and `0's` in the example about are values that are dynamically determined by my application (before the `SQLite` stage), so I can build them into the `SELECT` statement as such.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to determine the row with the largest addition of the `SELECT (Cx & 0)`. This is sort of a hamming distance function.

**Can anyone see what is incorrect about my `SELECT` statement above?** I've tried a large handful of variations, but nothing `SQLite` just hangs. A simple bitwise `SELECT` statement such as `SELECT (C1 & 1)` works just fine, outputting either a `0` or `1`.

**UPDATE:**

The answer below actually does not work. If I execute the subselect statement

```
SELECT (C2 & 0)
```

it will result in a `0` regardless of value. If the value in `C2` is `0`, then I am trying to count that as a match, and hence a `1`. Is this possible???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (C1 & 1) + (C2 & 0) + (C3 & 1) + ... + (C8 & 0) FROM MyTable
```